# Line breaks in Zend Navigation Menu labels

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have a need to create a <br/> tag in the display label for a menu item generated using Zend_navigation, but don't seem to be able to find a way to do so.

My navigation item is defined in the XML config as:

```
<registermachine>
<label>Register your Slitter Rewinder</label>                   
<controller>service</controller>
<action>register</action>
<route>default</route>
</registermachine>
```

I want to force a 
 tag in the output HTML between 'your' and 'slitter', such that it appears on two line as below:

Register your
Slitter Rewinder

However, I can't seem to do it. obviously using 
 in the XML breaks parsing, and using html entities means that the lable is displayed as:

Register your <br/>Slitter Rewinder

Has anyone had experience of this that can offer advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

there is no such option built-in you have to use a partial

```
$partial = array('menu.phtml', 'default');
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render();
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.menu

you may also try a hack with `<label><![CDATA[Menu label<br/>Second line]]></label>`

Answer (score 0):

I found a (hacky) solution:

I updated my navigation.xml to use `{br}` tokens wherever a `<br/>` tag is required, and then amended the base `Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/Menu.php` file as follows:

within `htmlify` function, changed

```
$this->view->escape($label)
```

to

```
str_replace("{br}", "<br/>", $label)
```

I could (and probably will) override the Zend Library Menu View Helper with my own at some point, but this at least cover it for now.

Answer (score -1):

there is a escapeLabels boolean used to convert html tags and it's true by default.

You can set your navigation like this

```
$this->navigation()
    ->menu()
    ->escapeLabels(false)
    ->...
```

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.View.Helper.Navigation.Menu.html#escapeLabels